Can I use the logging module to log the output of several, parallel async calls to some library to separate files?
Assume I have a library "lib" that logs some things via the logging module. I.e. there is a file ./lib/func.py that's somewhat like
import logging

func_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

async def f(x):
  func_logger.info(f"calculating f({x})...")
  f_x = ...
  func_logger.info(f"f({x}) = {f_x}")
  return f_x

and there is a ./main.py that's somewhat like
import logging
from lib.func import f  

async def main():
  return await asyncio.gather(f("a"), f("b"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

(Technically, I'm calling other functions that call something like f repeatedly, but I don't think this should matter here.)
Now I can log all of this to a single file by changing my main() to
async def main():
  lib_logger = logging.getLogger("lib") # this catches `func_logger`'s logs since its name starts with "lib." 
  lib_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  handler = logging.FileHandler("my_logs.log")
  handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  lib_logger.addHandler(handler)

  return await asyncio.gather(f("a"), f("b"))

but the logs will be all over the place.
So my question is: Is there a way to log f's logs ("a.log" and "b.log", say) into separate files for the different parallel calls without passing around a metadata object and changing the code in the lib folder?
Using context managers or setting logging variables globally may work if I ran tasks sequentially, but these approaches don't seem to work if everything is supposed to run in parallel.
